# Search arraylist for an instance variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that will return an object from a different class.

For example:

```
public Book searchTitle(String title) {
    for (Book book : library) {
        if (book.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            return book;
        }
    }

// If the book is not found, I have no return and the program won't compile.
//How do I make the method work in the case that the book is not found?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either return `null` or throw an exception if the `Book` is not found :

```
public Book searchTitle(String title) {
    for (Book book : library) {
        if (book.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            return book;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```